# Handling rotation and adjusting views programmatically (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Here is the problem I've been struggling with:

I'm creating a `view` programatically using loadView. 
Once it's loaded it looks just great in Portrait view. However, I want to handle rotation of the device. Therefore I use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method.

Within this method I call a function that adjust all the elements. What that function does is just goes through all my views and sets new `CGRect` to each of them. It works just fine on portrait orientations (up and upside-down), but once I change orientation to horizontal, it crops.

Two questions:

1. What is the most likely reason for such behavior?
2. How would you suggest handling device rotation without creating a separate view for horisontal / vertical orientations?

Comment: Well if they are being cropped you are obviously not setting them to proper `CGRects`. Also this is what stuts/springs and autolayout is designed for. Take a look at those and see if they are suitable for your needs.

Comment: It is not recommended to allow the upside-down view on iPhones, just so you know.  But as @Firo points out, it's likely you haven't set up your `CGRects` properly.  And you can use the `struts`/`springs` so that Autolayout will properly handle the rotation without doing anything programmatically also.

Comment: Are you targeting IOS 5.1 or early, if so you can use AutoResizingMasks to adjust the views, if you are targeting IOS 6.0 or superior you should use AutoLayout. 

For some views you will have to set the frame manually.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for your comments. I'll check `struts/springs`. The other thing I want to mention is that when I do `NSLog` for `CGRects` after resizing, they technically seem ok. So if I have an iPad rotated from portrait orientation to horizontal orientation, when I do `NSLog` , `CGRect` of a full-screen subview says it has been changed from `(0,0,768,1024)` to `(0,0,1024,768)`. However, the crop area looks like the coordinate system has not changed... Does if it make sense? (I don't have enough karma points to upload a picture, otherwise I definitely would).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the key part. When you are setting the frame at portrait view at view did load, view got the frame but when it change to the landscape it change but again from there i think you are not setting the frame for portrait view. use notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];


-(void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

        if((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
           // set frame here
        }else if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
          // set frame here too
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Why not just override `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`? Is there a real benefit for this if you want to handle the rotation in the visual `UIViewController`?

Comment: I have found in some scenario listing to notification is better but there is not other benefit i think